# TypeError in Symfony MIME Part When Sending Attachments with Laravel Mailable

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, mime-types

**Context:**
I am working on a Laravel application where I need to send emails with attachments using a custom Mailable class (`PdfEmail`). The email should include a dynamically generated PDF and other attachments from the service report model.

**Code:**
I have implemented the `PdfEmail` class, which includes methods to set up the email envelope, content, and attachments. The attachments are being fetched from storage and their MIME types are determined using the `ExtensionMimeTypeDetector` from the `League\MimeTypeDetection` package. Here is the relevant part of my `PdfEmail` class:

```php
public function attachments(): array
    {

        // save pdf temporarily
        // Define the directory where the PDF should be saved
        $directory = storage_path('app/public/service-reports/' . $this->serviceReport->id);

        // Check if the directory exists
        if (!is_dir($directory)) {
            // Create the directory, and make it recursive to create nested directories if necessary
            mkdir($directory, 0755, true);
        }

        // Now save the PDF in the created directory
        $pdfPath = $directory . '/service-report.pdf';
        $this->pdf->save($pdfPath);

        $attachments = [
            Attachment::fromStorage(
                path: 'service-reports/' . $this->serviceReport->id . '/service-report.pdf',
            )->withMime('application/pdf'),
        ];

        foreach ($this->serviceReport->attachments as $attachment) {

            $attachments[] = Attachment::fromStorage(
                path: $attachment->file,
            )->withMime($this->getMimeType($attachment->file));
        }
        // check each attachment content type
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            \Log::info($attachment->mime);
        }

        return $attachments;
    }
```

**Issue:**
When sending the email, I encounter a `TypeError` from the Symfony component used by Laravel. The error message is:

```
TypeError: The body of "Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\TextPart" must be a string, a resource, or an instance of "Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\File" (got "null"). in /path/to/public_html/vendor/symfony/mime/Part/TextPart.php:52
```

This error occurs when the email is being dispatched. It seems to be related to the way attachments are being processed or added to the email.However the code works totally fine on my local setup when I deploy it to hostinger it occurs only there

**Attempts to Solve:**

1. I logged the mime types for each attachments and they are not null

**Questions:**

1. What could be causing this `TypeError` in the Symfony MIME component when adding attachments?
2. Are there any issues with how I'm using the `Attachment::fromStorage()` method or the way I'm setting the MIME types for the attachments?
3. Is there a better way to handle attachments in Laravel Mailables that could avoid this issue?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've got the same problem. The error message can be a little bit misleading.
This error also is thrown if the given file path does not exist.

The ``Attachment::fromStorage`` method uses the ``local`` disk configuration which has it's root at ``storage_path('app')`` if not changed in your project. (see ``config/filesystems.php``)

I've solved this for myself by using ``Attachment::fromPath`` but I don't see why your code isn't working.  
  
You can set a breakpoint in ``vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php`` (``Mailable::attach``) and tinker with your attached file.